# Ruby exec caches python script responses

Tags: python, ruby, exec

I execute Python from Ruby using `exec` as follows:

**Ruby**

```
array = ['first string', 'second string']
array.each { |s| 
  result = exec("python print_string.py -s '#{s}'")
  puts result
}
```

**Python**

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Print string app')
parser.add_argument('-s', '--strg', type=str, help='shows string')
args = parser.parse_args()

print(args.strg)
```

2 problems:

- output is just "first string", while "second string" never got
  printed.
- changing "first string" to anything else and re-run ruby
  script still yields "first string"

Comment: well, i changed `exec` to `system`, and it's working now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're doing it wrong. Docs for [exec](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Kernel.html#method-i-exec), emphasis mine:

> **Replaces the current process** by running the given external command...

You want `system`, which just runs the command as a subprocess.